# How to change unshowing <div> components' size in react - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my react code.

```
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import products from "../products";

const HomeScreen = () => {
   return (
 <>
  <h1>Latest Products</h1>
  <Row>
    {products.map((product) => (
      <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
        <Product product={product} />
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
</>
);
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

And my screen looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oKmH.png)

I want to make all boxes that contain images the same size. How can I change the div that contains the image?

Also, I can see the HTML code below the image in the Inspect section of the browser. How can I access this HTML code in React Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

> we can used **height="250px"**

<img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top" alt={'productTitle'} height="250px"/>

Comment: product component in react